# Titan+dynamodb traversal backend performance

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-performance, titan

we try to use Titan (1.0.0 version) with DynamoDB backend like our recommendation system engine. We have a huge user’s database with their relationships. It contains about 3.5 millions of users and about 2 billions of relationships between users.
Here is the code that we used to create schema

https://gist.github.com/angryTit/3b1a4125fc72bc8b9e9bb395892caf92

As you can see we use one composite index to find starting point of traversal fast, 5 edge’s types and some properties.

In our case users can have a really big amount of edges. Each could have tens of thousands edges.

Here is the code that we use to provide recommendations online

https://gist.github.com/angryTit/e0d1e18c0074cc8549b053709f63efdf

The problem that the traversal works very slow. 
This one

https://gist.github.com/angryTit/e0d1e18c0074cc8549b053709f63efdf#file-reco-L28

tooks 20 - 30 seconds in case when user has about 5000 - 6000 edges.

Our DynamoDB’s tables has enough read/write capacity (we can see from CloudWatch that consumed capacity lower than provided by 1000 units.)

Here is our configuration of Titan

https://gist.github.com/angryTit/904609f0c90beca5f90e94accc7199e5

We tried to run it inside Lambda functions with max memory and on the big instance (r3.8xlarge) but with the same results...

Are we doing something wrong or it's normal in our case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The general recommendation with the system would be to use [vertex centric indexes](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#vertex-indexes) to speed up your traversals on Titan. Also, Titan is a dead project. If you're looking for updates to the code, [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org/) has forked the Titan code and continued to update it.

Comment: pantalohnes is right about using vertex-centric indexes. Also your query is looking for `has(USER_LABEL, USER_ID_PROPERTY, userId)` but the composite index isn't constrained by label. Try including `indexOnly(USER_LABEL)` when you [define the index](https://gist.github.com/angryTit/3b1a4125fc72bc8b9e9bb395892caf92#file-schema-L25-L29). http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_label_constraint